# Using .next() and .replace() to view images that share similar classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATE: Here's a jsFiddle, so maybe you can see what I'm trying to accomplish here. I don't think I'm great at explaining myself. http://jsfiddle.net/dh4qx/

I have images in a slideshow I want to be able to view one-by-one using a next or previous button. I can't for the life of me figure out why this function isn't working, or how to make one that does work.

Here's the JS function I'm trying to call when `div.next` is clicked:

```
function resNextClick(){
    var m = $('#slideshow2 img:visible').attr('class').replace(/\d+/, "");
    var $curr = $('#slideshow2 img:visible');
    var $next = $curr.next('img.' + m + '/\d+/');
    $curr.fadeOut(200);
    $next.fadeIn(200); 
};
```

I'm trying to fade the visible image out, and bring up the next image which shares the same class minus the digit. Hope that makes sense.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow2">
    <img class="oc1" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner1.jpg" />
    <img class="oc2" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner2.jpg" />
    <img class="oc3" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner3.jpg" />
    <img class="oc4" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner4.jpg" />
    <img class="el1" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/salinas1.jpg" />
    <img class="el2" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/salinas2.jpg" />
    <img class="el3" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/salinas3.jpg" />
    <img class="el4" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/salinas4.jpg" />
    <img class="el5" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/salinas5.jpg" />
    <img class="el6" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/salinas6.jpg" />
    <img class="el7" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/salinas7.jpg" />
    <img class="el8" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/salinas8.jpg" />
    <img class="ng1" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/nguyen1.jpg" />
    <img class="ng2" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/nguyen2.jpg" />
    <img class="ng3" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/nguyen3.jpg" />
    <a href="#"><div class="img-close">x</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="next">next</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="prev">prev</div></a>
</div>                                          
<div class="oc hide">
    <div class="desc">
        <h3>project: O'CONNER RESIDENCE</h3><br>
        <h3>civil engineer: BAI</h3><br>
        <h3>project location: CARMEL VALLEY, CALIFORNIA</h3><br>
        <h3>dates of my involvement: 06/2006-01/2007</h3><br>
        <h3>software: AUTODESK AUTOCAD 2007</h3><br>
        <p>This project is typical of the residential projects that I was involved with at BAI. The client was architect IDG of Pacific Grove and BAI provided civil engineering services and project permitting. As drafter and designer, I designed the grading, drainage, erosion control, retaining walls, and underground utilities. The lead engineer approved my design and I then executed about half the drafting, with the balance drawn by others to my redmarks. Following submittal and initial plan check, I also wrote responses to comments from Monterey County Planning, the local fire protection and watershed management districts, the California Department of Water Resources, and the California Coastal Commission.</p><br>
        <p>The civil planset as reproduced here was drawn in 09/2006 and submitted for permit in 01/2007.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="images">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="back">
                BACK
            </div>
        </a>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img class="oc1" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner1.jpg" /></td>
                <td><img class="oc2" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner2.jpg" /></td>
                <td><img class="oc3" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner3.jpg" /></td>
                <td><img class="oc4" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner4.jpg" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

As always, I appreciate all help and feedback.

Comment: `next()` selects the next element, and the selector is just a filter to see if it matches. Just remove the filter and do `$curr.next().fadeIn()`

Comment: you cannot use a regex as a selector, you can use the attribute starts with selector: `[class^=]`, but it wold be easier if you just give all the related images the same class, without adding a number to each one

Comment: @adeneo: I only want the `.next('img')` if it shares the class `m` plus one or more digits. In other words if the currently visible image has class `'oc4'`, the next image should be `img.oc1', not `img.el1`. It's quite possible that I'm just not explaining myself properly.

Comment: `next()` selects ***only*** the next element, if the next element in the DOM doesn't match the given selector, nothing is selected. It does ***not*** select elements other than the next one.

Comment: Which images are shown on page load and where?

Comment: @amaro: `div.images` is shown on page load. Clicking on any of those images brings up `#slideshow2` and shows the larger version of the corresponding image.

Comment: Need to ask one more question, so on load #slideshow2 is hidden and all elements inside as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing RegEx to selector. That is not valid to do!

Try this:

```
function resNextClick(){
    var m = $('#slideshow2 img:visible').attr('class').replace(/\d+/, "");
    var $curr = $('#slideshow2 img:visible');
    var $next = $curr.next('img[class^="' + m + '"]');
    $curr.fadeOut(200);
    $next.fadeIn(200); 
};
```

Comment: This needed a slight modification to work (`$curr.prev('img[class^="' + m + '"]')`), but that was exactly what I was looking for. @koala_dev was actually the first to propose the attribute starts with selector, but I think my mind was too wrought to figure out how to use it at the time. Thanks for the visual :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, you should use a class for each group of related pictures

```
<div id="slideshow2">
    <img class="oc" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner1.jpg" />
    <img class="oc" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner2.jpg" />
    <img class="oc" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner3.jpg" />
    <img class="oc" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/oconner4.jpg" />
    <img class="el" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/salinas1.jpg" />
    <img class="el" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/salinas2.jpg" />
    <img class="ng" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/nguyen1.jpg" />
    <img class="ng" src="/Users/justin/Desktop/res-links/nguyen2.jpg" />
</div>
```

And then something like this

```
function resNextClick(){
    var $curr = $('#slideshow2 img:visible'),
         cls = $curr.attr('class');

    var $next = $curr.next();

    // Toggle if next is the same class as this one
    if ($next.attr('class') === cls) {
        $curr.fadeOut(200);
        $next.fadeIn(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I don't think that will work here. They need to have different classes so that when you click on the thumb the proper image will be shown in `'#slideshow2`. I updated my OP with a fiddle, so maybe that will clarify for everybody.

Comment: Also, I've tried having multiple classes, but I haven't figured out a way to target a specific class of an element with multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

I made simple version of your slideshow (used code form ikaros45 answer as well)

You should be able to use it in your code and I hope it will help you.

Btw I am not sure is it correct way of doing it :)

HTML

```
<div class="img">

<div class="ox0">1</div>
<div class="ox1">2</div>
<div class="ox2">3</div>
<div class="ox3">4</div>

</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".img div").click(function(){  
         var selected_img = $(this).attr( "class" );  //get class of clicked element

         var group = selected_img.substring(0, selected_img.length - 1);  

         var set_img = $("#slideshow ."+group);

         selected_img = selected_img.substring(2);

         var showed = $('#slideshow img:visible');
         showed.hide();
         $(set_img[selected_img]).show();
         $("#slideshow").slideDown();

             /*
             *  for example you clicked on "ox1",
             *  var group - getting just text part of the class "ox"
             *  var selected_img - getting just number from class"1"
             *  var set_img - getting all elements in #slideshow with class "ox"
             *  $(set_img[selected_img]) - points which big img to open (ox[1])
             */

    });

$("#img-next").click(function(){
         var curr = $('#slideshow img:visible');
         var cls = curr.attr("class")
         var next = curr.next();


    if (next.attr('class') === cls) {
            curr.fadeOut(200);
            next.fadeIn(200);
        }
    else{

    var first_img = $("#slideshow ."+cls);
    curr.fadeOut(200);
    $(first_img[0]).fadeIn();
            /*
            * getting all elements with same class,
            * and showing first
            */ 

        }

   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dh4qx/6/

Comment: I really appreciate the input. Went with the `attribute starts with` selector. There's probably no way you could know this from the info I provided, but this will ultimately not work for me because 1. there will be at least one group of images that number up to 13, so the `length - 1` won't catch those and 2. the first object in the array is not the first image in the group, except in the case of the first group, of course.

Comment: Thanks, always happy to help. Regarding your comment, there is no length limit, group of images can be as long as you want it to be, there can be many groups of images it will pick the right one, with the right index. Also you don't need to define array (cls) with classes. Btw... I am not angry that you didn't pick my answer or something =) http://jsfiddle.net/dh4qx/8/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do an "attribute starts selector"

```
$curr.next($('*[class^="' + cls.trim() + '"]'))
```

That should give you the next item that has the same class prefix.  I also trimmed the class string due to the extra space.

If the length of the final selector is zero, then you're at the end and should just get the first.

Comment: This is probably very clear, but I'm not super experienced in js. I don't see how this code brings up the first in the group of shared prefixes if the current is the last. Here's how I accomplished this: `var $next = ($curr.next('img[class^="' + m + '"]').length) ? $curr.next() : $('#slideshow2 img[class^="' + m + '"]:first');` Your version looks much less clunky, but I just don't understand what how it is working.